# How to add Report Viewer tagPrefix to web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, reportviewer

I try to add ReportViewer to web.config so I don't have to add it on each page separately, but it doesn't work.

I add it to Assemblies:

```
<assemblies>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
</assemblies>
```

I also add the control:

```
<controls>
    <add tagPrefix="RSWEB" namespace="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms" assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
</controls>
```

And on my webpage I have:

```
<RSWEB:ReportViewer ID="MyRV" runat="server">
    <ServerReport ReportPath="/my_webpage_path" 
         ReportServerUrl="http://my_server/my_report" />
</RSWEB:ReportViewer>
```

The Error I get is:

```
Unknown server tag 'RSWEB:ReportViewer'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.  The controls tag should be this:

```
<controls>
    <add tagPrefix="RSWEB" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
</controls>
```